# How to insert two or more columns data into one column form one table to another table using Insert statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have two tables

```
Column_1 from SRC table will define to which columns
in the target table the SRC data values should get inserted into.
```

[image: Click here for the tables]

```
      SRC                                 TARGET
Col1    Col2    Col3  Col4      Tcol1   Tcol2   Tcol3  Tcol4
Test1    A         B    C       Test1      A          B       C
Test2    X         Y    Z       Test2      Z          X       Y
Test3    L         M    N       Test3      M          L       N
Test3    L         M    N       Test3      M          L       N
Test2    D         E    F       Test2      F          D       E
```

I want to insert the data like the way how I shown above, depends on the col_1 in src table, target columns should get mapped .

```
Insert into TARGET(Tcol1,Tcol2,Tcol3)
  select Col1 ,  Col2,  Col3 
  from src;
```

but here I dont how to handle this situation like target table is fixed .
for the first scenario first row from the src table will map as is as shown in the above sql but when it comes to 2nd row here I have to insert the values of first column to 2nd column of target table and in the same way 3rd row also.

Im writing one procedure but it will only work for fixed target and fixed source tables but how could I write sql script in this scenario.

Thansk in advance.

```
Insert into TARGET(Tcol1,Tcol1,Tcol1)
select  Tcol1,Tcol2,Tcol3
from 
select Col1 as Tcol1,
       Col2 as Tcol2,
       Col3 as Tcol3

from src;
```

Is there any way that I can take one function and map the values based on column1 in SRC table.

Comment: Your description is not very helpful.  What results do you want?  How do you define "first row"?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Comment: please look into the image attached in the question.Thank you

Comment: The logics behind that result is not clear to me. Say you have a number to identify rows (this must be some column, rows have no implicit order). For row 1, you want TcolX=colX; for row 2, you want Tcol1=col?, Tcol2=col1, Tcol3=col?; for row 3, … ? And what about rows after the third? What is the logic you need to implement?

Comment: It's still not clear to me the logic you need. Can you explain the reasons behind the expected result? As is, it's hard to help you

Comment: Column_1 from SRC table will define to which columns in the target table the SRC data values should get inserted into.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but trying to understand the need.

This exactly gives your expected result, with hardcoded values based on the value of `Col1`:

```
with src (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) as (
    select 'Test1', 'A', 'B', 'C' from dual union all 
    select 'Test2', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' from dual union all 
    select 'Test3', 'L', 'M', 'N' from dual union all 
    select 'Test3', 'L', 'M', 'N' from dual union all 
    select 'Test2', 'D', 'E', 'F' from dual
)
select Col1 as Tcol1,
       case (Col1)
        when 'Test1' then Col2
        when 'Test2' then Col4
        when 'Test3' then Col3
       end as Tcol2,
       case (Col1)
        when 'Test1' then Col3
        when 'Test2' then Col2
        when 'Test3' then Col2
       end as Tcol3,
       case (Col1)
        when 'Test1' then Col4
        when 'Test2' then Col3
        when 'Test3' then Col4
       end as Tcol4
from src      

TCOL1 TCOL2 TCOL3 TCOL4
----- ----- ----- -----
Test1 A     B     C      
Test2 Z     X     Y      
Test3 M     L     N      
Test3 M     L     N      
Test2 F     D     E
```

Is this correct? Does this logic apply to all the rows of your table? How to edit it?

Comment: This will work but only for few records, what if I have millions of records and 100 Column_1 values I cant write 100 case statements. Is there any other workaround that I can go with.

Comment: the logic… what is the logic? Why should `'Test2'` tell me that I have to populate the target table with `Col4,Col2,Col3` and `'Test3'` that I have to use `Col3,Col2,Col4`? How can I generalize this?